# Need hint: find minimum perimeter of a rectangle.

Tags: geometry

See problem below. Using calculus one finds that this happens when we have a square but this is from a geometry book so I dont think using calculus is the intended solution. Any hint for me? It might help that this problem is on the chapter titled: Areas of Similar Figures. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ and $b$ be the side of rectangle.

We have $a\cdot b=\Delta=\text{Constant}$.

By AM-GM inequality, we have $$a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}=2\sqrt{\Delta}$$

$$\text{Perimeter} \ge 4\sqrt{\Delta}$$

Now the min. Value of perimeter is $4\sqrt{\text{Area}}$ which can we obtained when $a=b$

(AM=GM only if the numbers are equal)